# C++, более одного объявления в выражении инициализации цикла for

Tags: c++, for, инициализация, объявление, выражение

Существует ли в `C++` способ объявить в выражении инициализации цикла `for` несколько переменных разного типа?

Например:

```
for (size_t s = 0, float f = 0.f; ; ) {}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Начиная с С++17 у вас есть вариант с *structured binding*

```
for (auto [s, f] = std::make_tuple(0, 0.0); ; ) 
{
  // Работаем с `s` и `f`
}
```

А до появления structured binding были лишь трюки вроде

```
for (struct { size_t s = 0; float f = 0.f; } sf; ; ) 
{ 
  // Работаем с `sf.s` и `sf.f`
}
```

или

```
for (struct { size_t s; float f; } sf = { 0 }; ; )
{ 
  // Работаем с `sf.s` и `sf.f`
}
```

Такой трюк не используется особенно широко, но тем не менее доступен со времен С.