# Инициализация внутри if

Tags: c++, c++17

В 17 стандарте появилась возможность инициализировать переменную внутри условия if (init; condition)
Значит я могу сделать так 
`if(int i =12; d < i){}` или так `if(int i,b = 10; i == b) {}` 
Но как проинициализировать некоторое количество переменных разных типов?

Comment: Имеет смысл разделять объявление переменных и выполнение условий.

Comment: @VTT Да, я уже заметил что конструкция получилась не читаемая.

Comment: Такой вопрос уже пару раз был

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ тот же самый, что и для множественных объявлений в `for`: [C++, более одного объявления в выражении инициализации цикла for](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017252/c-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-for)

Элегантного способа нет, но кому-то может понравиться вариант со structured binding

```
if (auto [a, b] = std::make_tuple(4, 3.14); a == b)
  std::cout << "Yay! Pi is " << a << "!" << std::endl;
else
  std::cout << "Nay... Pi is not " << a << "..." << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

Ну как мед, так ложкой...
Или "дайте воды попить, а то так есть хочется - даже переночевать негде!"...

Воспользуйтесь структурой, например:

```
if (struct { int i; double d; } x = {5, 4.5}; x.i > 5 && x.d < 4)
{
}
```

**Update**
Почему я не сторонник применения сруктурного связывания... Потому что по размеру имеем примерно то же, а вот по типам...

Сравните, [например](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/434e8820fa6d539f):

```
if (auto[a,b] = make_tuple(1,"ddd"); a > 0)
{
    cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(b).name() << endl;
}

if (struct { double a; string b; } x = {1,"ddd"}; x.a > 0)
{
    cout << typeid(x.a).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(x.b).name() << endl;
}
```

Здесь нужно предельно точно представлять себе, что именно и как именно инициализируется - скажем, не забыть дописать к 1 точку, или `s` к `"ddd"`...

Comment: Тогда уж `tuple`

Comment: @MrBin Чем это лучше?

Comment: Формально - ничем. Не формально - чуть труднее читать.

Comment: @MrBin Тогда зачем использовать то, что труднее читать? :)

Comment: Не, труднее читать со структурами (Не то написал, что хотел, но уже не исправить). Как я себе это представляю. Идёшь себе ты по коду функции. И тут бряк, какая-то структура в if. Имхо, мне это бы глаза мазолило сильно.

Comment: @MrBin а так идете - и бряк, какой-то кортеж. Точно так же мозолит глаза. Если же вы не о кортеже, а о структурном связывании - то при том, что выглядит оно попроще (не всегда :)), есть и минус - догадаться, что именно, какие типы скрываются под `auto`. Например, `if (auto[a,b] = make_tuple(1,"ddd");` и `if (struct { double a; string b; } x = {1,"ddd"};` - см. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/434e8820fa6d539f

Comment: Для минимального примера выигрыш очевиден, но когда тип становиться сложным и многословным... Ладно, чего уж - это сторона одной монеты.

Comment: @MrBin Сложный тип - мое imho - говорит о том, что что-то не очень продумано при проектировании... 2 переменные, ну, 3. Но больше - значит, надо пересматривать сам подход. Опять же напомню - imho...

Comment: Да, имхо. В том то и дело. От ситуации зависит. Правда сложный тип - это не обязательно что-то с архитектурой. Думаю, что boost.phoenix и boost.spirit этому пример.

Answer (score 1):

Чем бы дитя не тешилось... Такое было давно в 199...

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++98 if_pr.cpp
# include <iostream>
# define If(A,B,C,D) {A {if(B){C} else{ D}}}
int f(void){
  If(int x=0;int y=1;int z=2;int v=x+y+z;,v>0,
    return v;,
    return 0;)}

int main(){
  std::cout<<"f="<<f()<<"\n";
}
```

*Это просто шутка...*